# Using avfilter to properly mux multiple audio clips and images to one video

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

I have a little bit of experience working with FFmpeg but things just got a little complicated.

I need to render multiple audio clips and images into a video. My toughs was to use [avfilters](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) and set the various audio clips and images as input. I'm thinking using filters would take care of mixing audio clips that overlap and also take care of audio clips positions offsets in time.

Audio:
Use amix with asetpts values for each input to specify their start times.

Video:
??

I'm assuming that filter would return a sink with one audio stream and one video stream which I would then pass to the encoder?

Any ideas if what I want to do is even possible/recommended with filters? Any input greatly appreciated!

Comment: But, what this has to do with c or c++?

Comment: Well, the actual code I'm working with is written in C/C++. I'm not using the ffmpeg command line feature.